# How to calculate RGB values with identical perceived brightness

Tags: math, colors, language-agnostic, rgb

I'm trying to generate RGB colors with the same perceived brightness.

The function R*0.2126+ G*0.7152+ B*0.0722 is said to calculate the perceived brightness (or equivalent grayscale color) for a given an RGB color.

Assuming we use the interval [0,1] for all RGB values, we can calculate the following:

- yellow = RGB(1,1,0) => brightness=0.9278
- blue = RGB(0,0,1) => brightness=0.0722

So, in order to make the yellow tone just as dim as the blue one i can simply perform this simple calculation on yellow for each of the RGB components:

- dim_yellow = yellow * 0.0722 / 0.9278

However, when doing the opposite thing, thus "scaling" up the blue color to the same perceived brightness as the original yellow, the B component obviously exceeds 1, which cannot be displayed on a computer screen.

I guess the missing brightness from the excess B component could be "redistributed" to the R and G components, faking a brighter blue color. So what is the best general method to calculate those final RGB values?

Answer (score 3):

#### THESE AREN'T THE MATHS YOU'RE LOOKING FOR

> The function R*0.2126+ G*0.7152+ B*0.0722 is said to calculate the perceived brightness (or equivalent grayscale color) for a given an RGB color.

No this is incorrect, or at least incomplete. Yes, R*0.2126+ G*0.7152+ B*0.0722 are the *spectral* coefficients, but that is not the complete story.

First, Don't use the term brightness in this context. Brightness is not a measure of light, it is a perception, not a measurable quantity. When we are talking about light and colorimetry, use the term "luminance" (L or Y). Luminance is a linear measure of light, not perception.

Perceptual lightness, or L* (Lstar) from CIELAB, is based on human *perception* of changes in luminance. It is close to a power curve of about 0.43.

sRGB, the colorspace typically used for computer monitors and the web, is not linear like light, and it is also not exactly like the perceptual L* curve. sRGB's transfer curve is close to a 1/2.2 power curve. That is, the sRGB data/signal is raised to the power of 0.455, and then the monitor applies a power of 2.2.

### WHAT'S BROKEN

Your math isn't working because you are not taking the transfer curves into account. You must linearize the sRGB values before applying the coefficients. Then the sum of these will equal a luminance of 1.

#### #FFFF00 in sRGB equals 0.9278 in luminance, but this is an sRGB value of 96.76% or an L* value of 97.14%

#### #0000FF in sRGB equals 0.0722 in luminance, but this is an sRGB value of 29.79% or an L* value of 32.3%

Here's a chart of some values, expanding on your example:

[image: SRGB VS LUMINANCE VALUES]

So to answer the rest of your question, to get a blue that matches a higher luminance than the monitor is capable of requires desaturating it, adding R and G to increase the lightness.

In this chart, we have the fully saturated but darker red and green to match the 7% blue luminance, then we have 18% luminance (as in an 18% grey card), and here we have to desaturate the blue to bring the luminance value up.

### HOW TO CALC

First, you need to linearize the sRGB components, and THEN apply the coefficients, if you need to determine luminance. If you come up with some values doing math on linearized components, then you need to re-gamma encode to get back to sRGB.

I've discussed this is several other answers, [such as this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200738/10315269)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color model instead of RGB since you can easily achive what you want only modifying Value(Brightness) component.
The wiki page also contains how to convert RGB to HSV and back

EDIT:
Try to use [CIELAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) color space since it approximate human's vision

Comment: I know about HSL and HSV, but they don't do what you suggest. A blue hue with full saturation and value will still appear to be "darker" or "more dim" then a yellow hue with full saturation and value. So your answer does not solve my problem

Comment: @Askaga Yes HSV, HSL are not perceptually uniform.

Answer (score 0):

For a given hue, you can just multiply by the ratio of the desired brighness with the hues current brighness.

i.e. to find a red with the same brighness as blue we can

```
// l = .299 r^2 + .587 g^2 + .114 b^2
target_color = V(1, 0, 0);
desired_brightness = sqrt(sum(V(0, 0, 1) * V(0, 0, 1) * V(0.229, 0.587, 0.114)));
current_brightness = sqrt(sum(target_color * target_color * V(0.229, 0.587, 0.114)));
desired_color = target_color * desired_brightness / current_brightness
```

---

Demo https://tom-huntington.github.io/match-brightness/

I realized that Myndx's formula is better, however it is nonlinear so you have to use the secant method. We can square root the lumonicity to speed up convergence (since it the relationship is approximately square):

```
fn sRGBtoLin(colorChannel : f32) -> f32 {
  if ( colorChannel <= 0.04045 ) {
    return colorChannel / 12.92;
  } else {
    return pow((( colorChannel + 0.055)/1.055),2.4);
  }
}

fn luminance(color : vec3<f32>) -> f32 {
  var lin = vec3<f32>(sRGBtoLin(color.x), sRGBtoLin(color.y), sRGBtoLin(color.z));
  var coef = vec3<f32>(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722);
  //var coef = vec3<f32>(0.299 , 0.587 , 0.114);
  var rng = lin * coef;
  return sqrt(rng.x + rng.y + rng.z);
}

main() {
  var target_brightness = brightness(target_color);
  var xi = color * 1.5;
  var xim = color / 1.5;

  for (var i = 0u; i < 20; i++) {
  var bxi = brightness(xi);
  var bxim = brightness(xim);
  var xip = xi - (bxi - target_brightness) * (xi - xim) / (bxi - bxim);
  if (distance(bxi, bxim) > 0.000000000001)
  {
    xim = xi;
    xi = xip;
  }
}
```